# How did an event in Episode 8 of Westworld occur?

Tags: plot-explanation, westworld-tv

**Edited based on the events of Episode 9**
In the 8th episode of *Westworld*, it was reveled in a split-second flashback that Bernard had killed other people for Ford before - and many people believed the flashback showed Elsie being strangled.

It was reasonable to think that that could happen because Elsie told Bernard about her discovery and where she was going.

---

Then Episode 9 explicitly showed Bernard strangling Elsie.

---

However, in the episode where Elsie first went missing, she was just talking on the phone with Bernard. The abandoned theater where Elsie went missing is presumably miles away from where Bernard and Theresa were in that time, across the park.

So how is it that Bernard reached Elsie? Is there an in-show explanation, is it information we do not have, is it a plothole? Clearly he covered an extremely large distance in an extremely short time, and Ford was never present to help him at the theater.

Comment: Could you please make the title a little more explicit? It's hard to know if it's okay to read it if it just says it's a question with spoilers. I'd only know I want to read it after I read the spoilers! Maybe change it to something like "Given the events of <episode name>, how could a flashback be showing this event?"

Comment: There are still two episodes to go. How about just keep watching? Why this need to have everything explained right now?

Comment: @BCdotWEB It seems like they are done explaining this event. Maybe I will be proven wrong

Comment: Nonsense ^ They are withholding such information so people like you'd speculate ;)

Comment: So seems like a plothole now.

Comment: Invalidated by Episode 9. As far as the Park knows Elsie is **on leave**. ...and we now know that Bernard did, in fact, kill her.

Comment: @Paulie_D See revisions made to the question; I changed it from "how could Elsie possibly die" to "how did Bernard do this sorcery"

Comment: @BCdotWEB The season is over, and while the show may touch back on if Elsie is still alive next season, I'm fairly certain they won't touch on Bernard's methods of transportation. The question is still open

Comment: 1. A chokehold doesn't mean she was strangled and killed. 2. The show remains mysterious about certain aspects, including some timelines and some of the technology (e.g. look at how the guests go from docking to the wild west train). I find it pointless to speculate upon these until the makers provide an answer.

Comment: @BCdotWEB Please reread the question, it's been edited several times since I first posted it. (1) I acknowledge in the Q that Elsie may be alive; but Bernard still had to get to her. (2) I disagree - everything about docking and that process is detailed (for the most part) in [the site](http://discoverwestworld.com) or the show, and it cannot be a timeliney sort of mess (see my response to Catija's answer) It is clear that this is one quick sequence of events.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**An unspecified amount of time passes after Elsie hangs up.**

- Elsie finds a computer underneath the wooden floor of the stage.

     [image: Elsie 1]
- She calls Bernard and informs him about her find. When she hangs up, the computer is still attached to wooden floor she pryed open.

     [image: Elsie 2]
- It then cuts to Ford having a conversation with the kid-robot.
- When we return to Elsie, we can see that she has removed the computer from where it was before. And she has made herself comfortable on the chair.

     [image: Elsie 3]
- Elsie is going through the data on her tablet when she suddenly hears a noise.

     [image: Elsie 4]

So, **after Elsie hangs up on Bernard she clearly did things that weren't shown on screen**.

How long has she been sifting through the data she found? It might have been 5 minutes, it might have 1 hour ... I don't think there is any way to tell.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is that the person Elsie heard was not Bernard... let's say it was Ford.

Ford finds Elsie in the theater. He distracts her, has a conversation with her... he's good at that sort of thing... while doing that, he directs Bernard to meet them at the theater. Once Bernard arrives, Ford directs him to kill her.

There is no reason to require that her death occurred while she was on the phone with Bernard. Also, with a show so exquisitely planned as this, it's extremely doubtful that there would be such a glaring plot hole.

Comment: Do you mean directs Bernard to kill her?

Comment: Sorry, I was having a conversation with my husband about the show and we were talking about Arnold :P

Comment: "There is no reason to require that her death occurred while she was on the phone with Bernard" is correct, but within a span of at most three minutes of the phone call ending, Elsie was being strangled - or someone was clearly there - and that is not enough time for Bernard to make it to an area that deep within the park

Comment: This answer is now incorrect as of Episode 9. We now have a clear sequence of events in the theater - and Ford is nowhere to be seen, nor is he heard, at any point - and yet Bernard interacts with Elsie.

Comment: @Zxyrra I never said it *was* Ford... it was an example. Regardless, Elsie was not on the phone when she was strangled... I still contest that the simple fact is that there was more time between when Elsie was on the phone and when she was strangled and that is the central point of my answer.

Comment: My point is that we saw, through scattered clips, a complete sequence of events - see my last comment - in which **no one** distracts Elsie; and *I acknowledged* in another comment, as well as in the question, that no, she wasn't on the phone, but within several minutes of when they were, he was there. This answer is invalid because the show directly evidences that Bernard was the only one involved, and that there was no conversation in this event.

Comment: @Zxyrra You have **no way** of knowing how much time elapsed. The entire show is about fake-outs. It could have been 15 minutes or an hour for all we know.

Comment: I disagree completely. We are shown Elsie in consistent locations - she does not move off of her one path through any depiction of the scene, she does not age, and only the camera changes. If we were seeing hours passing, Elsie would not move this directly, she would be shown *here*, and then *there*, and then maybe *there*, but we see, in every depiction, the way in which she travels.

Comment: There is zero evidence that Elsie was killed, and in fact there's evidence she wasn't.